# Determine the Cell of TableView on which UIMenuItem was selected

Tags: iphone, ios5.1, uimenucontroller

I am displaying a context menu on the cells of a table view using `UIMenuController`.

```
UIMenuItem *ren = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Rename" action:@selector(onRenameItem:)];
/* .... then set menu visible on long press ...*/
```

the selector:

```
-(void) onRenameToken:(id) sender {
        /* ...Identify the selected cell??? ... */ 
    NSLog(@"Cell to be renamed is : %@",cell);
}
```

My question is how do I identify the cell which needs to be renamed. In other words, identify the cell for which the selector is performing?

PS: New to IOS programming. So pardon any terminology mistakes or silly questions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following discussion can help you out a little bit:
[How to show a custom UIMenuItem for a UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290828/how-to-show-a-custom-uimenuitem-for-a-uitableviewcell)
It doesn't seem that straightforward!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably subclass `UITableViewCell` and put the `onRenameItem:` (or `onRenameToken:`) method in there.

Since I'm not sure what you mean by "rename" exactly, either the cell could then rename itself or it could send a notification to some controller object to do the actual renaming.  Notifications can include an object and/or a user info dictionary, so it could tell the controller its own identity and any other details about what needs to be done.

Comment: rename is just an action I want to perform on the object displayed in the cell. There are some more options such as delete, activate, synchronize. So basically I want a generic way of identifying the cell for which a context menu is selected.

Comment: Can you elaborate on notification thing with some example or code? Thanks for your reply...