# UITableView long press menu - where is it coming from?

Tags: ios, uitableview

When I long press on a row in my UITableView (presented as a popover on iPad, FWIW) I see the "Copy" menu item appear. I don't have any UIGestureRecognizer attached to the table or the cell. The cell has a UILabel and a UIImageView.

Any guesses on where this menu item is coming from? Is this some kind of default on all UILabelViews, and if so how can I disable it?

Comment: Those are typically delivered by a UITableViewDelegate returning `YES` for `tableView:shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:`.  Do you have that in your source or in a parent class of the delegate?

Comment: Check this answer describing how you add menu to cells: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12291227/792677

Answer (score 0):

In function
    - (BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender

do

```
if ( action == @selector( copy: ) )
    {
        // turn off copy: if you like:
        return NO;
    }
```

It will resolve your problem.