# How to copy text to clipboard/pasteboard with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, copy, uipasteboard

I'm looking for a clean example of how to copy text to iOS clipboard that can then be used/pasted in other apps.

The benefit of this function is that the text can be copied quickly, without the standard text highlighting functions of the traditional text copying.

I am assuming that the key classes are in `UIPasteboard`, but can't find the relevant areas in the [code example they supply](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard).

Comment: Objective-C: http://hayageek.com/uipasteboard-example-read-write-share/

Answer (score 636, accepted):

If all you want is plain text, you can just use the [`string` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard/1622092-string). It's both readable and writable:

```
// write to clipboard
UIPasteboard.general.string = "Hello world"

// read from clipboard
let content = UIPasteboard.general.string
```

(When *reading* from the clipboard, [the UIPasteboard documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard) also suggests you might want to first check [`hasStrings`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard/1829416-hasstrings), "to avoid causing the system to needlessly attempt to fetch data before it is needed or when the data might not be present", such as when using Handoff.)

Comment: This may be working fine, but doesn't it happen that the user has images or files in it's copied content ?

Comment: `UIPasteboard.general.string` works in swift 4.x too

Comment: How can I copy font with font style?

Answer (score 71):

Since copying and pasting is usually done in pairs, this is supplemental answer to @jtbandes good, concise answer. I originally came here looking how to paste.

iOS makes this easy because the general pasteboard can be used like a variable. Just get and set `UIPasteboard.general.string`.

Here is an example showing both being used with a `UITextField`:

**Copy**

```
UIPasteboard.general.string = myTextField.text
```

**Paste**

```
if let myString = UIPasteboard.general.string {
    myTextField.insertText(myString)
}
```

Note that the pasteboard string is an Optional, so it has to be unwrapped first.

Comment: How can i copy text with font style. So i can use that font Style

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia, You can't copy text with the font style, but you can get the font info with `myTextField.font`. You can save that information separately and apply it somewhere else.

Comment: okay what If i copy text from my App and paste into WhatsApp or Any Other App Dose it support style?

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia, No, the iOS system `UIPasteboard` does not support styling. You can only handle styling within your own app.

Comment: According to [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard/1622092-string): "Do not use `UIPasteboard.general.string` to determine if a pasteboard contains string data. Instead, use the `hasStrings` property."

Answer (score 11):

Copying text from the app to the clipboard:

```
let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
pasteboard.string = employee.phoneNumber
```

Answer (score 11):

**SWIFT 4**

```
UIPasteboard.general.string = "TEXT"
```

Answer (score 7):

Write below the code where you want to Copying String or Text

```
UIPasteboard.general.string = "Dhaval Gevariya" // Put your String here
```

this is for read String from clipboard.

```
var readString = UIPasteboard.general.string
```

Comment: How would this answer differ from accepted answer and other existing answers?

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit.UIPasteboard

extension UIPasteboard {
  static func pasteToClipboard(_ content: String) {
    self.general.string = content
  }

  static func readFromClipboard() -> String? {
    return self.general.string
  }
}
```