# Menu for copying from Label

Tags: ios, swift3

I have code to copy the numbers from the Label.

I have a button for copying, how can I make it so that when I click on it open the menu that is in the photo and I could click the copy button?

[image]

```
@IBAction func copybutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIPasteboard.general.string = displayResultLabel.text
}
```

Comment: you only want the action sheet to carry the copy icon?

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani  I need to press this button to open this menu with the copy function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*With a meager amount of information from your question, hopefully I understand the problem correctly.*

I have created an example that has a `UIViewController` with a `UILabel` and a `UIButton`.

Whenever the button is pressed, the screen will display an action sheet menu with three buttons (`Copy`, `Paste`, `View Memory`).

And when the `Copy` button in the action sheet is pressed, we will copy the text of the label.

[image]

This is the code:

> **Note:**
>
> `UILabel` named `displayResultLabel`.
>
> `UIButton`'s action named `showActionSheetButtonAction`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var displayResultLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func showActionSheetButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let actionSheetController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        actionSheetController.addAction(
            UIAlertAction(title: "Copy", style: .default, handler: { [weak self] _ in
                guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

                UIPasteboard.general.string = strongSelf.displayResultLabel.text
            })
        )

        actionSheetController.addAction(
            UIAlertAction(title: "Paste", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                // Where to handle when the Paste button is pressed
            })
        )

        actionSheetController.addAction(
            UIAlertAction(title: "View Memory", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                // Where to handle when the View Memory button is pressed
            })
        )

        actionSheetController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        present(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need subclass the `UILabel`, and change some default things to achieve this, first you need to set `userInteractionEnable = true`, is `false` by default in `UILabel` and you need also override the property `canBecomeFirstResponder` which is also false by default after that you can show the menu becoming the label firstResponder and using the `UIMenuController` with longPressGestureRecognizer, class full code is here

**Use this UILabel subclass**

```
import UIKit

class ContextMenuLabel: UILabel {

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.showContextMenu))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
    }

    func showContextMenu()
    {
        self.becomeFirstResponder()
        UIMenuController.shared.setTargetRect(self.frame, in: self.superview!)
        let itemCopy = UIMenuItem(title: "Copy", action: #selector(self.copyAction))
        UIMenuController.shared.arrowDirection = .down
        UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [itemCopy]
        UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)

        debugPrint(UIMenuController.shared.menuFrame)
    }

    func copyAction()
    {
        UIPasteboard.general.string = self.text
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool{
        get{
            return true
        }
    }

}
```

**Result**

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi. I'm using your code and so far I get the copy menu. However, I'm trying to copy the message on a label in a tableView and the text from the label is being filled out from my database. When I paste what I just copied, I just get the name of the subclass. How can I make the text that is being copied be the string I'm getting from the database?

Comment: @XimenaFloresdelaTijera try debugPrint your label.text

Comment: You mean in the  func copyAction()
    {
        UIPasteboard.general.string = self.text
    }? Or in the label within the tableviewcell?

Comment: Ok, for TableViewCells, is different @XimenaFloresdelaTijera check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290828/how-to-show-a-custom-uimenuitem-for-a-uitableviewcell, you need to implement some UITableViewDelegate methods

Comment: Hi. I actually tried that answer and it didn't work. I was wondering if maybe this might be the issue. Cause the copying is working just fine, the problem is in the paste part of the solution. Not sure how to apply this to your subclass though. I believe the problem might be in the UIPasteboard.general.string  -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670290/how-to-copy-text-to-clipboard-pasteboard-with-swift/24670971#24670971

Comment: @XimenaFloresdelaTijera I had used this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290828/how-to-show-a-custom-uimenuitem-for-a-uitableviewcell with good results

Comment: really? which of the two answers? the one with 51 votes or the one with 8?

Comment: @XimenaFloresdelaTijera I will put my answer there updated ok? only for copy

Comment: @XimenaFloresdelaTijera check this and let me know https://stackoverflow.com/a/65888995/6190582