# How do I place a fixed string text Foo into a paste buffer?

Tags: ios, swift, copy-paste

I have some text that user will be able to paste later on into UITextField.
How can I copy that text programmatically?

Comment: use UIPasteboard

Comment: copy `UIPasteboard.general.string = "Hello world"` and for paste `let content = UIPasteboard.general.string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By from [jtbandes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24670971/11077258)'s Answer

- To Copy

```
@IBAction fucn btnCopyClick(_ sender: UIButton)
{   
    UIPasteboard.general.string = YourTextField.text!
}
```

- Paste

```
let contentText = UIPasteboard.general.string
```

Comment: yes, thanks. I figured that from the commends by the two guys who commented under the question.

Comment: Actually i done this same yesterday, so this is my one of favourites ;)