# How to copy a String by pressing a button inside UITableView Cell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitableview, copy-paste

I have an array of data "electricity" which I am getting from the server. I have a button inside a UITableView Cell name "copyPinButton". Inside 'cellForRowAt indexPath' I am placing the data necessarily. I want to copy a string value that I am getting from the server by pressing 'copyPinButton'. Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit

class ElectricityBillTransactionHistoryViewController: BaseViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var electricityTransactionHistoryTableView: UITableView!
    private var electricity = [Electricity]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        electricityTransactionHistoryTableView.delegate = self
        electricityTransactionHistoryTableView.dataSource = self
        electricityTransactionHistory()
    }
    func electricityTransactionHistory() {
        webserviceHandler.transactionHIstory(onCompletion: { (TransactionHistoryResponse) in
            if TransactionHistoryResponse.code == 200 {
                self.electricity = TransactionHistoryResponse.data?.electricity ?? []
                self.electricityTransactionHistoryTableView.delegate = self
                self.electricityTransactionHistoryTableView.dataSource = self
                self.electricityTransactionHistoryTableView.reloadData()
            }else {
                self.showDialog(title: nil, message: TransactionHistoryResponse.message ?? K.Messages.DefaultErrorMessage, onDefaultActionButtonTap: nil)
            }
        }, onFailure: { ( _) in
            self.showDialog(title: nil, message: K.Messages.DefaultErrorMessage, onDefaultActionButtonTap: nil)
        }, shouldShowLoader: true)
    }
    

}
extension ElectricityBillTransactionHistoryViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return electricity.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "electricityTransactionHistoryTableViewCellId", for: indexPath) as! electricityTransactionHistoryTableViewCell
        let electricityData = electricity[indexPath.row]
        cell.electricityBillHistoryTitleLabel.text = electricityData.packName
        cell.electricityBillTransactionIdLabel.text = "\( electricityData.trackerID ?? 0)"
        cell.electricityBillAmountLabel.text = "\(electricityData.paidAmount ?? 0)"
        cell.electricityBillPaymentDateLabel.text = Util.getFormattedDateString(inputDateString: electricityData.purchasedDate ?? "", inputDateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", outputDateFormat: "dd MMM yyyy - h:mm a")
         return cell
    }
    
    
}

class electricityTransactionHistoryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var electricityBillContainerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var copyPinButton: UIButton!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var electricityBillImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var electricityBillHistoryTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var electricityBillAmountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var electricityBillMonthLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var electricityBillTransactionIdLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var electricityBillPaymentDateLabel: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        copyPinButton.layer.masksToBounds = false
        copyPinButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        copyPinButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        copyPinButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.5, height: 0.5)
        copyPinButton.layer.shadowRadius = 3
    
        electricityBillContainerView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        electricityBillContainerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        electricityBillContainerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        electricityBillContainerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 0.5)
        electricityBillContainerView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func copyButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Copy to what ? clipboard ?

Comment: Is the problem getting the values ? or copying them

Comment: Yes to Copy to clipboard & there is no issue  getting the values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy text to clipboard/pasteboard with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670290/how-to-copy-text-to-clipboard-pasteboard-with-swift)

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIPasteboard` directly

```
// write to clipboard

UIPasteboard.general.string = "Hello world"

// read from clipboard

let content = UIPasteboard.general.string
```

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24670290/8192960) for more detailed  answers

Answer (score 0):

You can copy text or string using `UIPasteboard` like below:

```
@IBAction func copyButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
   UIPasteboard.general.string = "Your value"
}
```

Comment: Already answered, if there is a difference or added value missing from the first answer would be better if mentioned.