# Need to show both Copy and Delete popup on uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

i am trying to show popup with 2 options in it (Copy and Delete) but at the moment code is only showing Copy in it please view my code below.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender
{
    return (action == @selector(copy:)) || (action == @selector(delete:));
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(copy:))
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
        [pasteBoard setString:cell.textLabel.text];
    }
    if (action == @selector(delete:))
    {
        NSLog(@"delete pressed!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, check this SO link.
[SO link for Custom Menu Item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290828/how-to-show-a-custom-uimenuitem-for-a-uitableviewcell)
It says, even though we you expect tableView canPerformAction: to support custom selectors while the documentation says it supports only two of UIResponderStandardEditActions (copy and/or paste);

Comment: but then how is that working on Whatsapp and lots of other apps?

Comment: They might also be using the same approach.
But, sure that default delete will not show up as menu item as in your current code. I believe, you need to implement some more customization mentioned in that link.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
return (action == @selector(copy:)) || (action == @selector(delete:));
```

with

```
return (action == @selector(copy:)) && (action == @selector(delete:));
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: i did that but it doesn't even showing any popup. not even copy

Comment: I'm not sure how this would ever work, given `action` could only be one of the values, not both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this library to implement swippable buttons which supports a variety of transitions and expandable buttons.

https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell

This library is compatible with all the different ways to create a UITableViewCell and its working fine on latest versions of iOS as well.

[image]

P.S. I suggest you to provide UI like this.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but its a chat application so i think this will look bit weird. :)