# iOS - How to add bubble with text/buttons over cell in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

I really have no idea how to call this feature, music app had it up to 8.4, it looks like on the screenshot. I want to implement it in my app so when user presses the cell the "bubble" with 2 option buttons shows up.
I am interested in how to make it happen in Obj-C but I'm sure people will apreciate the answer written in Swift. Thanks
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He1Vg.png)

Comment: Thats called Menu. Have a look at: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uimenucontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing exactly the same thing as what you want.
To do so, you have to create your own view controller, not UIMenuItem. The screen capture is as follows.

[image]

What I'm doing is to create a viewController as popup (PopoverMenuController), and adding a tableView as a subView for menu.
In the same way, you can add whatever UI controls you want instead of tableView.

Here is how you use my PopoverMenuController.

```
var myPopupMenu: PopoverMenuController!

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // make cell fully visible
    let tableCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    tableView.scrollRectToVisible(tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath), animated: false)
    // pop up menu
    myPopupMenu = PopoverMenuController()
    myPopupMenu.sourceView = tableCell
    var rect = tableCell.bounds
    // I'm adjusting popup menu position slightly (this is optional)
    rect.origin.y = rect.size.height/3.0
    rect.size.height = rect.size.height / 2.0
    myPopupMenu.sourceRect = rect
    myPopupMenu.addAction(PopMenuAction(textLabel: "MyMenu-1", accessoryType: .none, handler: myMenuHandler1))
    myPopupMenu.addAction(PopMenuAction(textLabel: "MyMenu-2", accessoryType: .none, handler: myMenuHandler2))
    present(myPopupMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func myMenuHandler1(_ action: PopMenuAction?) -> Bool {
    // do some work...
    return false
}

func myMenuHandler2(_ action: PopMenuAction?) -> Bool {
    // do some work...
    return false
}
```

To transltae to Obj-C should not be a big effort.
I put souce code of PopoverMenuController.swift [here](https://github.com/beshio/sample-code). This controller is self-contained and it has a description on how to use.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Look up how to implement UIMenuController on a UITableViewCell

[How to show a custom UIMenuItem for a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290828/how-to-show-a-custom-uimenuitem-for-a-uitableviewcell)

Comment: 1) The screenshot does not show a menu. 2) Don't post an answer this is just a link to another answer.