# How can open custom pop up when click on button in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to open a popup box like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRHJY.png)

please help me if any one knows

Comment: Use `UIPopOverPresentationController`.

Comment: You can show and hide a tableview on button click with animation.

Comment: Did you check this? https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmenu Note that the developer has not updated it since a long back you may require to use a fork version of it. Which is more updated.

Comment: I think, this fork is more helpful to you: https://github.com/alex081293/kxmenu because it allows to show the menu items in a scroll view. Helpful, if you will have multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this with UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate and tableView. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086363/ios-how-to-add-bubble-with-text-buttons-over-cell-in-uitableview/41093196#41093196) for more detail. The source code is available [here](https://github.com/beshio/sample-code).

Comment: I think, user requested an answer in objective-c.

Comment: oops! I didn't realized tag has only obj-c.

Comment: Alright, maybe the user can convert it to objective-c?

Comment: I hope so. Actually, it's a small code and should not be difficult to translate to obj-c.